# How to connect Flink remotely via JMX?

Tags: jmx, apache-flink

For my upcoming bachelor's thesis I want to develop a tool that collects system and application data from Apache Flink and sends this data in some kind of "events" to another system. This tool will be installed on Flink job- and taskmanager nodes. Beside data from linux system utilities like dstat I would like to collect JMX data.

My problem is, that I couldn't figure out how to connect via remote JMX connection by using a port to Flinks jobmanager. Although the collector will be on the same machine, I really try to avoid using a --javaagent to access JMX data of Flink's JVM.

Another problem is, I have a local docker setup based on https://github.com/apache/flink/tree/master/flink-contrib/docker-flink and updated to flink-1.0.2, that I cannot connect via jconsole because I don't know how to "open" a JMX remote port for the job- and taskmanager.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance, any ideas very appreciated.

Comment: This might be interesting for you https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-1502.

Comment: Thanks! But does that mean, it's not possible to connect to Flinks JVM from another? For me now it's possible to connect a local running jobmanager(no docker) with JConsole to read JVM, but not remotely to Flink on Docker. The JIRA issue seems to be more about Flink-specific metrics, but plain JVM data, like from jconsole would be enough for the moment...

Answer (score 7):

Solved!

I needed to add `env.java.opts: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9999 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false`

in flink-conf.yaml.

No it's possible to connect the jobmanager via jconsole.

Comment: I'm getting port already in use from task manager. I can however connect to job manager. How can I give them different ports so that they don;t conflict?